# Web scraping using selenium and BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

Below is the inspect of the element

```
<div class="input-group ref-container ">
<input id="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" name="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" aria-labelledby="label.incident.assignment_group" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="PeopleSoft Reporting ONLY" ac_columns="u_full_name" data-type="ac_reference_input" data-completer="AJAXTableCompleter" data-dependent="" data-dependent-value="" data-ref-qual="" data-ref="incident.assignment_group" data-ref-key="null" data-ref-dynamic="false" data-name="assignment_group" data-table="sys_user_group" class="form-control element_reference_input  " style="; " spellcheck="false" onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXTableCompleter(gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'), 'incident.assignment_group', '', ''); e.ac.onFocus();})" aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="AC.incident.assignment_group">
<span class="ref_dynamic_placeholder">A new record with this value will be created automatically</span>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="lookup.incident.assignment_group" name="lookup.incident.assignment_group" type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Lookup using list" aria-haspopup="true" data-for="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" data-type="ac_reference_input" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Look up value for field: Assignment group" data-original-title="Lookup using list">
<span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
</button>
</span>
</div>
```

How can I write the value `"PeopleSoft Reporting ONLY"` into a variable?

Comment: reformat the code please

Answer (score 2):

You can select by `id=` attribute. For example:

```
txt = '''<div class="input-group ref-container "><input id="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" name="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" aria-labelledby="label.incident.assignment_group" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="PeopleSoft Reporting ONLY" ac_columns="u_full_name" data-type="ac_reference_input" data-completer="AJAXTableCompleter" data-dependent="" data-dependent-value="" data-ref-qual="" data-ref="incident.assignment_group" data-ref-key="null" data-ref-dynamic="false" data-name="assignment_group" data-table="sys_user_group" class="form-control element_reference_input  " style="; " spellcheck="false" onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXTableCompleter(gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'), 'incident.assignment_group', '', ''); e.ac.onFocus();})" aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="AC.incident.assignment_group"><span class="ref_dynamic_placeholder">A new record with this value will be created automatically</span><span class="input-group-btn"><button id="lookup.incident.assignment_group" name="lookup.incident.assignment_group" type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Lookup using list" aria-haspopup="true" data-for="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" data-type="ac_reference_input" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Look up value for field: Assignment group" data-original-title="Lookup using list"><span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

s = soup.select_one('#sys_display\.incident\.assignment_group')['value']
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
PeopleSoft Reporting ONLY
```

The same with:

```
s = soup.find(id="sys_display.incident.assignment_group")['value']
print(s)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I get the below error whatever  I try : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to extract the text **PeopleSoft Reporting ONLY** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='sys_display'][name*='incident'][aria-labelledby$='assignment_group']").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'sys_display')][contains(@name, 'incident')][contains(@aria-labelledby, 'assignment_group')]").get_attribute("value"))
  ```

---

However as per best practices to extract/print the desired text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".data-row"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='data-row']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As using:

- `find_element_by_*` you face *NoSuchElementException*
- *WebDriverWait* you face *TimeoutException*

Possibly the element is not within the *Top Level Content* and may be within an `<iframe>`. Now to address [**NoSuchElementException**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511) discussion.

Comment: Getting the below the error  :   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Try the second part with _WebDriverWait_

Comment: Now i get this error :  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: So that implies the element is not within the _Top Level Content_ and possibly within a `iframe`. Now to address _NoSuchElementException_ follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715) discussion.